# How to resolve DLL hijacking in C# console application

Tags: c#, security, dll

An insight on the issue.

I have create one console app in C# which takes a DLL at run time.
However while going through the security scans, it give me DLL hijacking output.

Comment: Please clarify whatever it is you mean by: 1. "takes a DLL at runtime" and 2: "DLL hijacking output".

Comment: How are you loading a DLL into your process? Do you understand how the GAC works? Are you targeting .NET Core (incl. .NET 5) or .NET Framework? Does this happen locally or in production? What about when debugging from within VS?

Comment: Can you get something out of this, perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741828/how-can-i-proctect-my-net-application-against-dll-hijacking